# SQL 2008 - Transaction log is full

Tags: sql-server-2008, log-files, tsql

We have some issues with the transaction log files
We have SQL Server 2008

Our situation:

- Every night, we have many jobs that runs on the server by SQL Agent
- Some jobs stop because the transaction log for database is full
- Everything is fine when we run failed jobs in morning

All databases recovery mode is Simple, except 2 databases (but we never get log full on them)

And the log file have the following option:

- Autogrowth
- 10 %
- Unrestricted (some have 2TB)

Disk space is not a problem, the hdd has never exceeded 60%
Data and log have their own hdd

Do you have any idea how to correct the transaction log full problem?

UPDATE
Log File size
msdb ~150mb
 
master ~2mb
 
temp ~265mb
model ~2mb
The biggest log file is ~3GB, 3 have ~1GB, and the others are less than 1 GB
 
But we got log full on a 650mb and on a 27mb log file size

Comment: Do you have a maximum size set on tempdb (or any of the other files, for that matter)? This may be your problem.

Comment: @Randolph Potter, no maximum size. The autogrowth is unrestricted

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the following MSDN article on [Troubleshooting a Full Transaction Log (Error 9002)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175495.aspx)

Comment: ok, so the plan suggestes is to make the DB maintenance plan - Shrink - On Demand and then change the recovery mode into "simple" ?

Comment: If the simple recovery mode is sufficiently granular for your environment, then you can change to it and reduce the resources used by your transaction log.

Answer (score 1):

Check transaction log of system db (msdb, master, temp, etc)

Comment: msdb ~150mb, master ~2mb, temp ~265mb, model ~2mb
The biggest log file is ~3GB, 3 have ~1GB, and the others are less than 1 GB
But we got log full on a 650mb and on a 27mb